# Return neighbors index in an 3x3 grid

Tags: code-golf, grid

Alright, my second attempt at a code golf, let's see how this goes.

Pretend you have a 3x3 grid of digits, from 0 to 8:

```
 0 | 1 | 2
---+---+---
 3 | 4 | 5
---+---+---
 6 | 7 | 8
```

Return the neighbors the input has as indexes of the array.

**Rules:**

- It's code golf, so shortest answer wins.
- The pretend array's index can start at 0 or 1. (all examples use 0 though)
- The submission can be just a procedure/function/method, but an example would be nice
- The returned value can be in any order (if the input is `0` you could output either `13` or `31`)
- If you want, the output can be a list of numbers, e.g. `[0,4,6]` instead of `046`
- Diagonals don't count, as shown by the examples.

**Examples:**

```
0 -> 13
3 -> 046
4 -> 1357
```

Comment: It looks like this challenge could benefit from some time in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1). You can post your challenge there so others can review it and help you out with it before posting it to main. From your examples I'm guessing you're not counting diagonals. You may want to add this to the question itself. You also mention the requirement to output the indexes of the array that are neighbors. I think this could just be hardcoded for a 3x3 grid. Would it maybe be better to output the neighbors themselves?

Comment: Just so you know, *frowned upon* isn't really something we do here; hardcoding the output is either allowed or it isn't. Since it's usually pretty hard to define what exactly counts as hardcoding, I'd personally just allow it or give the grid size as an additional input.

Comment: Can the output be a list of numbers, e.g. `[0,4,6]` instead of `046`?

Comment: @Laikoni Yes, a little bit too late because you've already answered it.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, I wasn't quite sure how to put it. I like how the C and python answers did it, by providing both, but having the non-hard coded answer as the final. I wanted to encourage algorithms rather than hard-coding, but I wasn't sure if it was even possible (without overly long answers), and I didn't want to have no answers to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 13 bytes

```
9Ḷ,d3ạ/S€=1T’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/5cMc2nRTjh7sW6gc/alpjaxjyqGHm/8PtQLb7//8GOgrGOgomAA)

#### How it works

```
9Ḷ,d3ạ/S€=1T’  Main link. Argument: n (0, ..., 8)

9              Set the return value to 9.
 Ḷ             Unlength; yield [0, ..., 8].
  ,            Pair; yield [[0, ..., 8], n].
   d3          Divmod 3; yield [[[0, 0], ..., [2, 2]], [n:3, n%3]]].
     ạ/        Reduce by absolute difference, yielding
               [[|0 - n:3|, |0 - n%3|], ..., [[|2 - n:3|, |2 - n%3|]].
       S€      Sum each, yielding
               [|0 - n:3| + |0 - n%3|, ..., [|2 - n:3| + |2 - n%3|].
         =1    Compare the sums with 1.
           T   Truth; yield all 1-based indices of 1.
            ’  Decrement to yield all 0-based indices of 1.
```

Comment: The rules state: "The pretend array's index can start at 0 or 1." - you can drop the Decrement at the end.

Comment: @steenbergh I assume I'd have to take 1-based input as well then, which costs as many bytes as it saves.

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
9:qWIe1Y6Z+i)BPf
```

The array is 1-based, that is, contains numbers from `1` to `9`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29pVRjumWoYaRalnanpFJD2/78pAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/hvaVUY7plqGGkWpZ2p6RSQ9t8l5L8hlxGXMZcJlymXGZc5lwWXJQA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `2` as an example.

```
9:q  % Push [0 1 2 ... 8]
     % STACK: [0 1 2 ... 8]
W    % Rise to 2, element-wise
     % STACK: [1 2 4 ... 256]
Ie   % Reshape as 3-row matrix (column-major order)
     % STACK: [1   8  64;
               2  16 128;
               4  32 256]
1Y6  % Push [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]
     % STACK: [1   8  64;
               2  16 128;
               4  32 256],
              [0   1   0;
               1   0   1;
               0   1   0]
Z+   % Convolution, maintaining size
     % STACK: [10  81 136;
               21 170 336;
               34 276 160]
i    % Take input, n
     % STACK: [10  81 136;
               21 170 336;
               34 276 160],
               2
 )   % Get n-th entry (1-based; column-major order)
     % STACK: 21
B    % Convert to binary
     % STACK: [1 0 1 0 1]
P    % Flip
     % STACK: [1 0 1 0 1]
f    % Find: gives indices of nonzeros. Implicitly display
     % STACK: [1 3 5]
```

Comment: Wat? How did you come up with this?

Comment: @RobertFraser These challenges about finding neighbours always suggest to me a convolution approach. But convolution inherently adds the neighbours' values, so I needed to be able to separate them at the end---that's the powers-of-two and binary expansion parts

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
GridGraph@{3,3}~AdjacencyList~#&
```

Uses a graph instead of an array. `GridGraph@{3,3}` constructs a 3x3 grid-shaped graph, shown below, which Mathematica helpfully labels with the numbers 1–9 for the vertices by default. Then `~AdjacencyList~#&` tells you the neighbours of a vertex.

[image: The 3x3 grid graph]

Comment: Gotta love those builtins...

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
{24,135,26,157,2468,359,48,579,68}[[#]]&
```

1-indexed. Just looks up the answer. Can someone do better in Mathematica?

Comment: I'm surprised that there isn't a builtin for this. Like I'd expect there to be a builtin to find all neighbors of an element in a 2D array, but I'm not sure, I don't know anything about Mathematica other than the fact that it has too many builtins.

Comment: You can save a byte by using 0-indexing and `31[420,51,...,75][[#]]&`.

Comment: You can use `GridGraph@{3,3}~AdjacencyList~#&` for 32 bytes, with 1-indexing.

Comment: @lanlock4 Awesome! Please make that an answer so I can upvote it!

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, <s>42</s> <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```matlab
@(n,x=~e(3),y=x(n)=1)find(bwdist(x)==1)
```

1-based index.

[Verify all test cases.](http://octave-online.net/#cmd=arrayfun(%40(n%2Cx%3D%7Ee(3)%2Cy%3Dx(n)%3D1)find(bwdist(x)%3D%3D1)%2C1%3A9%2C%27Un%27%2C0))

Explanation:

```matlab
x=~e(3);         % create a 3*3 matrix of zeros
x(n)=1;          % set the element with index n to 1
d=bwdist(x);     % compute the distance transform of the matrix
find(d == 1)     % find where the distance is 1.
```

Example: `n = 2`

```matlab
x =

   0   0   0
   1   0   0
   0   0   0
```

(In Octave data is stored column-wise.)

```matlab
d =

   1.00000   1.41421   2.23607
   0.00000   1.00000   2.00000
   1.00000   1.41421   2.23607
```

logical index where distance is 1:

```matlab
d == 1

 1   0   0
 0   1   0
 1   0   0

find(d ==1)

 1
 3
 5
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 71 bytes

```python
lambda n:filter(abs,[(n-3)*(n>3),(n+3)*(n<7),~-n*(n%3!=1),-~n*(n%3>0)])
```

1-indexed
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JYpBCsIwEADvvmItCLu6kYYcCsXmI@ohxUYW2lVibqX9eiw6pxmY2N3KGKb@EUDbKGMeEob@w1dU4@iI6h0x6unnl4Z4NbrZwe07S2zWf/ia7lTiK4GAKKSgzwEt25raHWy8k2jGal7AeJiX6rytU8goHFGIqHwB)

---

Getting the result from a predefined list of  results is shorter (46 bytes):

```python
[13,204,15,406,1357,248,37,468,57].__getitem__
```

0-indexed
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#DcqxDoMgFAXQvV/x4gTJrREBsU3aH1FDHMC8QdoQNuO3o2c@8TPXSWn0nYGyMN0Apa1Db0ZoBzOMsG5pvd9C4RJ272v8ZWLiRHlNWxAv@X7Q7Z85FdEcJz2/dJxNe799LYIRBUsp6wU)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>100</s> <s>92</s> <s>91</s> <s>83</s> <s>78</s> 74 bytes

```
p(n){putchar(n+48);}f(n){n>3&&p(n-3);n<7&&p(n+3);n%3&&p(n+1);--n%3&&p(n);}
```

1-indexed. Thanks to @Neil for saving 4 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@1@gkadZXVBakpyRWKSRp21ioWldmwYSy7MzVlMDyuoaa1rn2ZiD2dogtipEXNtQ01pXF8YD6vqfmVeikJuYmaehyVXNxZmmAVQAM1g9Jk9d0xokaIpN0AJDsPa/IZcRlzGXCZcplxmXOZcFlyWXoQEA)

**Hardcoded version, 56 bytes**

```
l[]={13,204,15,406,1357,248,37,468,57};
#define L(n)l[n]
```

0-indexed

Comment: In the first version, can you not write `n>3&&p(n-3)` etc. to save 4 bytes? In the second version, can you not write `l[]=` to save a byte?

Comment: Are you sure your code is currently correct? When I try the test cases it fails for all three.. :S [Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/c-clang#dYrRCsIgGEbvfQohxhQxDAdFjvUi3Yw5mVD/hmk3w2d30@qyq8P5znewMDyCHnH78trOx6lDFjx@9hbIe7aarghjQwRVO5fgh6l3pL5DXQZD5L/QFLrRBwdYKBTTQoCuvyew5kJVNHmDTt72yCW9CgXtOQv7SFUKO2Xh/KtZYkob) Could you perhaps provide a working TIO-link, perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen TIO link added, and it seems that I forgot to edit the actual code on the last edit... Oh, well. Your link is working correctly too, but notice that my answer is 1-indexed whereas the example test cases are 0-indexed.

Comment: @Steadybox Ah, you're indeed right. I missed the 1-indexed part, my bad. Thanks for adding the TIO. +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>74 71</s> 68 bytes

```hs
f n=[x|x<-[n-3,n-1..n+3],0<x,x<10,gcd 3x<2||n-1/=x,gcd 3n<2||n+1/=x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#Jc2xDoIwFIXhVzkhDpC2CHYyaX0CmRhrB6JBGLgQxXiHvnuluJ18/3BiD7KOAxvlSGlJqi5LEtrLyrBkU1fyeX9AszmFsMWj5T/QDiKBj1M3EiymbmmQ3xjqguWztuvrSjjgPcxfMIRAlkqW1m55Dy4KuO3y7OMP) Uses a 1-indexed grid. Example usage: `f 3` returns `[2,6]`.

Edit: Saved <s>3</s> 6 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen!

---

For <s>77</s> 75 bytes, the following function `#` works for an arbitrary grid size `m`:

```hs
n#m=[x|x<-[n-m,n-1,n+1,n+m],0<x,x<=m*m,gcd x m<m||n-1/=x,gcd n m<m||n+1/=x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#LczBCoJAEAbge0/xox203bWMjrs9gZ06moGklIcZRY2G8N3NlQYGfr4Z/plDcrlMYk3OhjSbVLPyS4U@WNFiHe1IPx8VBGRpmpaXvZNV@C/KSzFT2TAcqnaDZYbmW8Ma9HVZZbwSld0F0U1gzuje43XsM8YWw6v9LO1KIfCXwKfVIkG49sQx8jRJfLwfi/n0Aw)
For each `n` the list `[n-m,n-1,n+1,n+m]` contains all four neighbours. For each entry `x` in this list we check `-1<x` and `x<m*m` to make sure `x` is not above or below the grid, `mod n 3>0||n-1/=x` to enforce the left grid border and `mod(n+1)m>0||n+1/=x` for the left border.

Comment: You can use `[n-3,n-1..n+3]` and `gcd 3n>1`.

Comment: Oops, never mind that `gcd` part. It should have been `<3`, and then breaks for `n==0`. You *might* be able to use that trick if you change everything to `1`-indexed.

Comment: Oh, and the `n/=2&&n/=5` can be replaced by `mod x 3>0`. (Or the `gcd` version with reindexing, which might now be used twice.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>51 48</s> 45 bytes

```ruby
->a{[a+3,a-3][a/6..a/3]+[a+1,a-1][a%-3..a%3]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7P9r2uXWB2dqG2sk6hrHBudqG@mp5eobxyrDRQzBIoZAsVUdY2BgqrGsbX/C0pLihXSog1itex1uKAcQ2SOETLHGJljgswxReaYIXPMkTkWIM5/AA)

Create 2 arrays, with vertical and horizontal neighbours, then select one or more of them.

#### Ruby hardcoded, 44 bytes

```ruby
->a{%w(13 024 15 046 1357 248 37 468 57)[a]}
```

... Not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 51 bytes

```
lambda x:[x+3,x-3][x/6:x/3+1]+[x+1,x-1][x%-3:x%3+1]
```

Based on a previous version of my [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113987/18535) answer, I found it interesting because it was mostly the same code, using a different trick, and produces the same result. Getting this one right helped me golf the ruby answer a little more.

Basically, ruby has it shorter because the array slice index are inclusive, python needs a `+1` to compensate.

#### Explanation

Get the 2 arrays (vertical and horizontal neighbours), then select one or both based on some calculations.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 63 bytes (hardcoded)

```
int c(int i){return new int[]{31,420,51,640,7531,842,73,864,75}[i];}
```

0-indexed
(Reversed order output because `024` and `046` aren't valid integers.)
<s>Still working on a non-hardcoded version, but</s> I can assure you it won't be shorter..

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#fY3LCoMwEEX3fsUsEwjiIz7Ab@jKpbhIU1sGNIoZW4rk2@2UdtvexcCdA@fa0XgPJ9ijCMCTIbRwoCOw4n1R7utA2@rADQ/gT9fveap0lqgiVaVOVFVwr3WmqlzVpeYeOuybcLBv2c4j@77a@4wXmAw6cUVnRmhpRXfrejCS54HTPj0NUzxvFC/MaHTCikTK5jfN/1L9oSEKxws)

---

**82 bytes**

```
String c(int n){return""+(n>3?n-3:"")+(n<7?n+3:"")+(n%3>0?n+1:"")+(--n%3>0?n:"");}
```

1-indexed
Based on [*@Steadybox*' C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113910/52210)

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#fY7BCoJAEEDvfsWwEOwiSmIRaOgXdPIYHbbNYmEdxR2DEL/dJrRjze3Ng3ljnPYeTtoijEEA4EmTNTBX1Ft8gJEWCVCNfU1Dj0KEEou0xCjNhFAMx0OJ4Rc2abFlTBaMonXxwXyaAbrh6vj42ni29gYNl@XdonawJM8X0Ip/AZ7q5alu4naguGNHDqWRiVL5b7v7a/eLnYJpfgM)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 9 bytes

```
kd⁻ṪÞo1⁾i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJrZOKBu+G5qsOebzHigb5pIiwiIiwiMyIsIjMuNC4xIl0=)

```
kd⁻ṪÞo1⁾i­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
        i  # ‎⁡value of program at index of input
kd⁻Ṫ       # ‎⁢digits 0-8 in a 3x3 square
    Þo     # ‎⁣grid neighbors
      1⁾   # ‎⁤flatten by 1
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 34 bytes

```apl
⌷∘42 531 62 751 8642 953 84 975 86
```

1-indexed, hardcodes the values :(

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Uc/2Rx0zTIwUTI0NFcyMFMxNDRUszIB8S1NjBQsTBUtzUyD/v9ujtgnEKeV61DcVqNhNwRDOMoGzTP8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript + lodash, 71 bytes

```
f=a=>_.range(9).filter(b=>a>b?f(b).includes(a):[,1,,1][b-a]&&b%3|a%3<2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 116 bytes

```
@set c=cmd/cset/a%1
@set/ar=%1%%3
@if %1 gtr 2 %c%-3
@if %r% gtr 0 %c%-1
@if %r% lss 2 %c%+1
@if %1 lss 6 %c%+3
```

0-indexed.